# Assertion message is not printing in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, assertion

i have write a code to verify the text using assertEqual. The code is running fine but after successful verification assertion message is not printing.

```
def test_c_lms(self):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver = self.driver
    dlms = Dashbaord_LMS(driver)
    dlms.LMS_method()

    self.assertEqual(dlms.lmshead_v, 'LIVE MONITORING SYSTEM',
                     'Lms Heading verified')  # heading verification
    self.assertEqual(dlms.onlineag_v, 'Online Agents',
                     'Online agents heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.active_v, 'Active Agents',
                     'Active agents heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.agents_on_break_V, 'Agents on Break',
                     'Agents on breaks heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.agent_chatting_V, 'Agents Chatting',
                     'agents chatting heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.agent_not_chatting_V, 'Agents Not Chatting',
                     'agents not chatting verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.total_chats_V, 'Total Chats',
                     'total chats heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.average_speed_V, 'Average Speed of Answer',
                     'average speed of answer heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.occupancy_v, 'Occupancy',
                     'occupancy heading verified')
    self.assertEqual(dlms.visitors_text_v, 'Visitors',
                     'Visitors heading verified')

    t = self.driver.current_url
    self.assertEqual(t, 'https://new.beelinks.solutions/dashboards/lms'
                     , 'url matched')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **sucessful assertion doesn't print** anything in python.

But you can use a function which prints your values instead.